# How to nest multi lines string in csh?

Tags: linux, string, shell, csh

I am trying to set variables with string, and construct a more complex string by nesting them.
For readibility purpose, I have these strings on multiple lines using \ characters.
When I try to do this without the \ it seems to work, but I can't have something working with it.

Example of not working code :

```
set String_A = "Make \
Something \
End"

set String_B = "${String_A} \
And add \
Something else"

set String_C = "${String_B} Finally something good"
```

Example of working but unclear code :

```
set String_A = "Pretty long and unreadable"

set String_B = "${String_A} And add Something else"

set String_C = "${String_B} Finally something"
```

Could you find a solution where I meet my two requirements ? (Readability on multi lines, and nested strings using variables ?)

Have a good day,
Julien

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multi-line variable in tcsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305742/multi-line-variable-in-tcsh)

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes and no space before the slash

```
set String_A = 'Make\
Something\
End'

set String_B = '${String_A}\
And add\
Something else'

set String_C = '${String_B} Finally something good'

echo $help:q
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to work effectively if I use only 'something' string nested together.

In my script I have quite a lot of other strings that I would like to avoid editing, that are set using double quotes (").

I get an error {Unmatched ".} if I try to mix these two types of string. 
If I want to mix those two types of string is it possible ?

Comment: In other words, what is the fundamental difference between ' and " for strings in csh ?

Comment: Also with your method, ${String_A} seems to not be replace by the value of the variable, but stays like an actual string. So it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Yes, output is `${String_A}
and add
someting else` (over 3 lines.

Comment: Try the `var = \`cat\` << EOS .... EOS` version mentioned elsewhere in that answer. Good luck to all.